# Default login or Social login

Tags: wordpress, authentication

Is there a way to find out what way user is logged in, default wordpress login (admin/user/...) or social login?
I'm using AccessPress Social Login Lite plugin, and need to show WpAdminBar only for wp users, and hide for those who is logged in by any social link.

Comment: surely you can do that thing but for that you need to check with database that what are the difference between both type of user. check user meta and user table. you will find something different and than your task is done with simple if condition.

Comment: Thank you very much @Aki. In my case I must get user meta 'duetype'.

Comment: Hope now you are able to do that or share that meta fields with me i can let you know how you can do it

Comment: I just need to write get_user_meta($user_id, 'deutype'); what will return either social network name (in my case 'facebook'), or empty string, if user is logged in after default registration.

Am I right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
add_action('init','userAdminToolbar');
function userAdminToolbar()
{
 $currentUser = wp_get_current_user();
 $userId = $current_user->ID;
 $soicalLoginStatus = get_user_meta($userId, 'deutype'); 
 if($soicalLoginStatus != '')
 {
    show_admin_bar( false );
 }
}
```